# Create intersection DataFrame with same dimensions

Tags: python, pandas

I have the DataFrame's

```
     x    y
b  0.0  1.0
a  1.0  0.0
c  0.0  1.0
```

and

```
     x    y
b  1.0  1.0
a  1.0  0.0
c  0.0  0.0
```

I would like to find the intersection of values (where the value at a given position in each DataFrame is 1) such that the output is:

```
     x    y
b  0.0  1.0
a  1.0  0.0
c  0.0  0.0
```

I have tried using the intersection method with no success. I need the most efficient method possible since the dimensions of my actual DataFrames are 50000 * 50000. Any pointers?

**UPDATE**

Using the methods suggested here results in maxing out my 16GB RAM. Why is this? The resulting DataFrame has the same shape?

Cheers

Comment: multiply: `df1.mul(df2)` ?

Comment: Wow. Can't believe I didn't think of that. 1 * 0 == 0. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use the AND operator `df1 & df2`

Answer (score 0):

Try `(df1.astype(bool) & df2.astype(bool)).astype(float)`.

I tried solution proposed by *Ken*, but got:
*TypeError: ufunc 'bitwise_and' not supported...*